# How to get my Python list to accept each dictionary created by user input?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
#line used to accept user's net pay
net_income = float(input("Please enter your net income: "))

#line used to query if user wants to input budgeted line item
add_exp_item= input("Do you want to add an expenditure item (yes or no): ").lower()

#intialization of dictionary and list used to store user input 
budget = []
budget_listItem = {}

#loop used to continuously query for budgeted expense item
while True:
    #line used to store description of expense
    d= input("Enter name description of expense: ")
    
    #line used to store numerical value of expense
    a = float(input("Enter cost/budgeted amount: "))
   
    #line used to store the type of expense 
    t = input("Enter category type that such as whether it is a want, need, saving: ")
    
    #line used to store all user input in dictionary 
    budget_listItem.update({'description': d, 'amount': a, 'type': t})
    
    #testing line to to see what is stored in dictionary
    print(budget_listItem)

    #line used to store each expense line (each dictionary) in a list
    budget.append(budget_listItem)
  
    #testing line to check what is in list of dictionaries
    print(budget)
    
    #line used to query if user wants to enter another line item
    add_exp_item= input("Do you want to add an expenditure item (yes or no): ").lower()
    print("*************************************************** \n")

    #bool used to break out of loop if user no longer wants to enter line items
    if add_exp_item == "no":
        break

print("\n \n")

#final print of list of dictionaries
print(budget)
```

Each time my code would loop it will update the dictionary but instead of storing the initialdictionary, my list will replace the previous input (dict) with the new input. I have also attach a snip of results. Please help! [Code Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN4F9.png)

Edit: I had actually copied the wring version where i had budget.update() instead of budget.append().

Comment: Lists don't have an `update` method in Python. Instead of `budget.update(budget_listItem)`, you might be needing `budget.append(budget_listItem)`.

Comment: Please, edit your question to include your actual code. `budget` is a list and `budget.update()` would produce `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'`, i.e. this code did not produce the output from the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, i had accidentally used the wrong version when posting. It has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code. You can only append to a list.

Also when you update a dictionary, the old values will get updated.
Hence you need to create new dictionaries each time and push it into the list.

```
#line used to accept user's net pay
net_income = float(input("Please enter your net income: "))

#line used to query if user wants to input budgeted line item
add_exp_item= input("Do you want to add an expenditure item (yes or no): ").lower()

#intialization of list used to store user input 
budget = []

#loop used to continuously query for budgeted expense item
while True:
    #line used to store description of expense
    d= input("Enter name description of expense: ")
    
    #line used to store numerical value of expense
    a = float(input("Enter cost/budgeted amount: "))
   
    #line used to store the type of expense 
    t = input("Enter category type that such as whether it is a want, need, saving: ")
    
    #create new dictionary for each input
    budget_listItem = {'description': d, 'amount': a, 'type': t}
    
    #testing line to to see what is stored in dictionary
    print(budget_listItem)

    #line used to store each expense line (each dictionary) in a list
    budget.append(budget_listItem)
  
    #testing line to check what is in list of dictionaries
    print(budget)
    
    #line used to query if user wants to enter another line item
    add_exp_item= input("Do you want to add an expenditure item (yes or no): ").lower()
    print("*************************************************** \n")

    #bool used to break out of loop if user no longer wants to enter line items
    if add_exp_item == "no":
        break

print("\n \n")

#final print of list of dictionaries
print(budget)
```